# using import in reactJs when using CDN

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using reactJs with CDN and my project is online. I have independent react components where i want to import 1 component in another file. Using "**`import {Container} from './reactScript'`** " is giving me "`Uncaught Syntax Error: https://soccious.com/static/login.js: Unexpected token (8:16)` ". The error points to import keyword. How else do i import another  component?

Comment: use babel transcompiler to convert es6 code to es5, use webpack or browserify to bundle your js file.

Comment: that is what you do when you use the npm. Im doing it without npm, the CDN way. Your solution doesn't help

Comment: that still works out, cuz browserify is just a bundler, doesnt matter whether its from npm or your own code.

Comment: How do i use it?